# How to skip a batch file error when using a repeated command

Tags: batch-file, youtube-dl

I'm using a batch file and youtube-dl to download videos from a list in a txt file.

The code is short:

```
@ECHO off
youtube-dl -a list.txt
PAUSE
```

Occasionally I get an http error 404 because I've missed a letter when copying & pasting the URL. When the error occurs, it ends the script. How do I get the script to go to the next line in the txt file?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
youtube-dl -i -a list.txt
```

The -i option should ignore any errors and go to the next link in the batch file.